# Contacting a suspended user via meta?

Tags: discussion, chat, account-suspension

How can a user suspended on this site that is also not allowed to chat communicate with other users on this site ?
Can this be done via meta or is there another proper way to do that ?

In my case I would like to contact a user, who was suspended because of "voting irregularities" whatever that means, and they  are not even allowed to chat. Is there any possibility to communicate with them ?

To note, in the specific case the user is suspended "network wide."

Comment: @MartinSleziak So, there is no way to contact him , right ?

Comment: Well, you can always leave comment on some of his posts. Any user can add into their personal settings whether or not they should get email about new notifications. Moreover, in this specific case the users clearly still visits the site. (They just cannot post anything on the site or in chat.) The user profile says that this user was last seen about 30 minutes ago.

Comment: What can be discussed on this site at all, if even such questions are downvoted ?

Comment: If the user has an associate account to another SE site, and not suspended there, and you can communicate with them there (if you have an associate account too) by leaving comments under a post by that user. Such way may not be encouraged though.

Comment: An issue with your post is that it mentioned a suspended user. It was in a way relevant to do this, but generally it is discouraged. I removed it.

Comment: who is that user ? And what voting irregularities mean?

Comment: @Theoneandonly usually it is not made public who gets suspended. Voting irregularities can mean various things. It can mean using other accounts to vote for oneself, excessive voting on other accounts, etc.

Comment: @user759001 there is a guideline not to bring up suspensions of other users. The post did not follow this guideline. If because of this it received downvotes it is not clear how this is a conduct that requires moderators to intervene against the voters. I did intervene in that I brought the post in line with the guidelines and subsequently the score even improved.

Comment: Okey I've removed my comment @quid , it is just my impression not about this specific post. I didn't know such guideline. We postpone the discussion about my concern in future posts of Meta to know who is right you or I. Thus if you interpret that I was wrong in my comment I'm sorry.

Answer (score 6):

At least often, though  not in the specific case due to the network-wide suspension, it can indeed be done via "meta" yet not the per site meta, rather the main Meta:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/

The chat server of that site https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ is separate, and a suspension on this site, and the SE chat suspension that frequently comes with it, does not affect the chat rooms there.

This is basically "by design"; it is not a suspension evasion to use that chat while being suspended. Obviously, one can get suspended there, too, but there is no automatism.

Moreover, as recalled by Martin, the Stack Overflow chat server is also separate: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Since you have mentioned the chatserver for [meta.se], I will also add link directly to chat: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ Also [so] has a separate chatserver: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ (IIRC the three chatservers are separate as far as suspensions go.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak  But the particular suspended user referenced in the OP seems to have been suspended network wide.  Would that not also prohibit chat, network wide?

Comment: @amWhy Yes, this particular user cannot chat there, exactly as you say. As far as I can tell, this is answer to a general inquiry rather than something tailored for this specific case. quid explicitly said in the answer: "often, though it seems not in the current case...."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @MartinSleziak

Answer (score 1):

> How can a suspended user that is not allowed to chat communicate with other users on this site?

Well, not via the site; of course, that's what the suspension is for. It's up to them if they expose any other means of contact (Twitter, website, email) on their profile page. It seems this user uses his real name (and even their job on another profile) which might help finding them via Google.

---

Oh, by the way, you can't ping users with a comment under a post they don't have any interaction in any way.

Comment: "Well, not via the site; of course, that's what the suspension is for." In principle, yes. It seems that the system does not prohibit such behavior. Do you consider it as evading a suspension if one communicates with other users on the site during a chat suspension?

Comment: One is suspended *here* because they cause trouble *here*. What people do outside Stack Exchange is none of our business. They can't communicate here (except that I have seen a case where a user communicated to other *by editing their profile* - that *would* be evading a suspension).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. What I meant is that if a user is on a *chat* suspension in *this* site but communicate/chat with other users *within* the SE network by commenting under posts on the main site or other SE sites, do you consider it as suspension evasion?

Comment: @T.S your question is a bit orthogonal to what is asked. Your question seems to  be about a case where a user is suspended *only* in chat, yet not on (all) SE sites. Such a user then might use the features of the / an SE site, such as comments,  to communicate. This might result in them posting content, e.g. comments, that is off-topic. If excessive, it might have consequences, but use of comments for side-conversation has a certain tradition, and predates chat.

Comment: @quid: OP says "How can a *suspended user that is not allowed to chat* communicate with other users on this site ?" I thought Peter's talking about chat only suspension. Maybe he is talking about something else though.

Comment: Later, @T.S, the OP clarifies: "In my case I would like to contact a user, who was suspended because of "voting irregularities" whatever that means, and they are not even allowed to chat. Is there any possibility to communicate with them ?"

Comment: @T.S I think that Peter meant is suspended on this site and can also (or therefore) not use chat. I clarified the post in that sense. // Indeed amWhy points to the place of the post that makes this clear.